# How to add sub headers based on the header field in a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to break the field into subfields in a csv file using python. I've googled it but i didn't found any anything.

for now I'm adding header using the following code:

```
header = ["Triage","Total Alert","Investigated","False Positives","Tickets Created"]

output_file = open('test.csv','w',newline='')

 
writer.writerow(header)


data = [index,total_count,ia_count,fp_count,tkt_count]

writer.writerow(data)
```

by running it into loop i'm adding the rows into csv. But Now i want to add other subfields into csv but i'm unable to do so and didn't fine any help. This is what i want:

- Break the Tickets Created field into subfields like Low, Medium,High,Critical

CurrentOutput:
[image]

Desired Output:
[image]

For now i've trid to add it using panda and numpy library but it dind't go well.

Comment: How did you try to add the sub headings? Couldn't you just do the same thing as you did for the header but with spaces for the empty columns?

`sub_fields = ['', '', '', '', 'Critical', 'Medium', 'High', 'Low']`

Comment: There's no such thing as a sub-header in CSV, where there is no way to specify the span of a field.

Comment: You could have Tickets_Critical, Tickets_Medium, Tickets_High, Tickets_Low. Like blhsing stated, cell spanning, like you did with "Tickets Created", is only a spreadsheet feature; CSV cannot do that. Or like shawn_caza suggested, you could just write a second row, and you'll get something that looks close to what you want.

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding.
Yeah I can't do this with csv. I guess I would go with the solution suggested by @ZachYoung. If i find out any solution related to this, I would love to share over there.